# BASH: setting an environment variable from within my script doesn't set it anywhere else - how can I export globally? Simple example within

Tags: bash, unix, environment-variables

```
PROMPT> pwd
/Users/jon/dev/test

PROMPT> ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x   3 jon   102B Aug 27 21:34 ./
drwxr-xr-x  14 jon   476B Aug 27 21:33 ../
-rwxr-xr-x   1 jon   147B Aug 27 21:34 init*

PROMPT> cat init
#!/bin/sh
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
export SCRIPT_HOME=${DIR%/bin}
echo "SCRIPT_HOME has been set to: $SCRIPT_HOME"

PROMPT> ./init
SCRIPT_HOME has been set to: /Users/jon/dev/test

PROMPT> echo $SCRIPT_HOME

PROMPT> why did that command not work?
-bash: why: command not found

PROMPT>
```

Comment: `export` makes a shell variable available to any *subprocesses* of the shell in which it was defined, but not to the *parent* process of the shell in which was defined.

Comment: source the script instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you should try the following :

```
PROMPT>. ./init
```

Notice the extra dot `.` and the space between `./init`. That is important. It is similar to `source init`.